# Does a std::list point to the same memory?

Tags: c++, list

I was wondering if a `std::list` pointed to the same memory, like a `std::vector`, of if when an element is, for example, `push_back`ed, it simply is allocated using `new` and it points to the other elements (with `next` and `prev`)?

```
template<class T>
    struct node
    {
    node<T> *next, *prev;
    T value;
    };
```

Comment: vector, list are two different containers. vector holds contiguous memory locations and I don't see any reason to have references to previous, next elements.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on linked-lists to aid in your learning. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html

Answer (score 1):

Only `vector` is guaranteed by the standard to return a pointer to a contiguous block of memory for the address of the first element, so not so for `list`

Answer (score 1):

First, `std::vector` does not point to the same memory after `push_back`, at least not all the time: if the allocated size is insufficient, `std::vector` would re-allocate its internal data block, and so it would point to a different place in memory.

Unlike `std::vector`, `std::list` is a linked list, so its head will put to the same place in memory after a `push_back`. However, `std::list` does *not* support fast random access to its elements.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard does not precise how any container is implemented (`list`, `deque`, `vector`, ...) however the requirements are so strict that it can generally be inferred nonetheless.

For example, a `std::vector` of size `N` must guarantee that `&vec[0] + i = &vec[i]` for `i` in `[0, N)` (which is fancy wording to mean it has a contiguous storage).

On the other hand, `std::list` must guarantee that:

- insertion/removal is `O(1)`
- insertion/removal does not affect any *other* element of the list: iterators to them are not invalidated and their address is stable

This stability implies a node-based container, so the canonical implementation is a doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Neither do. Both containers own their elements and so inserting an element into the container will involve creating a new element. It has to be this way. Here's why:

```
{
    SomeContainer <T> container;

    {
        T element;
        container.push_back(element);
    }
    // Here
```

At this point, `element` is out of scope and no longer exists, but the container is still in scope. So the container *must* have created its own `T` with a different scope.

Comment: this isn't exactly the case if a move constructor exists for T.

Comment: It still is. A new element will still be created, just in an efficient way.